# How to pass function object to a function as callback c++

Tags: c++, functor

as little follow up to this: [C++ lambda function without C++0x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25564178/c-lambda-function-without-c0x)

I have created the lambda function as a function object without c0x

the question now is:

- how to pass it as a callback/function pointer to another function?

My first try was like this, but it didn't work:

```
Lambda Obj( C, D);
command ( Obj.operator()(typeA A, typeB B));
```

I marked the other question to early i guess, so noone looked at the edit.

Comment: Just use a C++11 compiler. For such things, view older C++ compilers as obsolete.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: If only it was always so easy. Companies are reluctant to upgrade compilers, and it would not be unlikely to have a boss who prohibits C++11.

Comment: I dont have the choice.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1840029/passing-functor-as-function-pointer) answers your question.

Comment: Post your entire translation unit and any compiler errors you are getting, unedited.

Comment: Is something wrong with `template <typename Functor> void command(Functor);`?

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot find `std::function` in `std::tr1::function` or via `std::function` or via a compiler upgrade...

Write your own `std::function`-like type eraser, or use `boost`, or use 'the fastest possible delegates' (that should google to a complete implememtation), or pass both a `this` pointer and a method pointer as `template`-type-deduced arguments to a function, or pass a `template`-type-deduced copy of the function object to the function.

Note that the last two options require the function's body to be exposed (such as in a header file).

Or convert the function object into a `void*` style C callback.

I would go with C++11, and failing that `boost`, and failing that fast delegates, failing that write a type eraser myself, failing that stick body in header and template+pass a copy (unless function is simple, in which case do this first), and failing that pvoid C style.

Comment: +1 The dual-cadence in this answer is awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Boost.Bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/bind/bind.html):

```
void command(boost::function<void()> func)
{
    func();
}

Lambda Obj(C, D);
command(boost::bind<void>(Obj, A, B));
```

*(or maybe you wanted to have):*

```
void command(boost::function<retType(typeA, typeB)> func)
{
    retType ret = func(A, B);
}

Lambda Obj(C, D);
command(boost::bind<retType>(Obj, _1, _2)); // placeholders
```

Using templates (the *STL's way*):

```
template <typename F>
void command(F func)
{
    func(A, B);
}

Lambda Obj(C, D);
command(Obj);
```

[Live demo link.](http://ideone.com/xmY6m8)

Comment: Thanks, i wanted the second, it compiled.